# Query whether string field contains digit in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

How do I query for all entities where a string column contains a digit in Entity Framework?

e.g.

```
"100 Main Street" // match
"Will advise" // no match
```

I *really* don't want to do this:

```
myclass.Property.Contains("0")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("1")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("2")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("3")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("4")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("5")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("6")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("7")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("8")
|| myclass.Property.Contains("9")
```

Comment: Umm... care to share why you voted me down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if the column contains a digit:

```
where SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%[0-9]%", myClass.Property) != 0
```

Comment: Performs better than the Enumerable.Range solution provided by @Oleksii.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using Contains method on array of digits:

```
var digits = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(s=>s.ToString()).ToArray(); 
var result = YOURCONTEXT.YOUR_TABLE
                        .Where(n => digits.Any(d => 
                                      n.YOUR_FIELD.Contains(d)))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Super elegant and terse.  Very nice!